# 1150: The protected attribute can only be used on class property definitions?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, admob

```
   admob.addEventListener(AdmobEvent.onBannerReceive,onAdReceived);


  protected function onAdReceived(event:AdmobEvent):void {

  if(event.type==AdmobEvent.onBannerReceive){

    trace(event.data.width,event.data.height);

  }
}
```

That is my code and im getting this error:

1150: The protected attribute can only be used on class property definitions

Comment: So people use WTF at Office, too. Cool.

Answer (score 2):

Well you haven't used this inside a class, but probably inside a frame in Flash IDE, right? Just remove the 'protected' keyword and it will work ;)